# advanced searchbox with php

Tags: php, search

If you visit the simple machines (SMF) forums you will notice at the top of the page they have a searchbox and next to it they have drop down box which allows you to fine tune your search to the different parts of the site and I was curious if there was a script that would allow me to add this same functionality to my site or any places where I can find some examples that I could learn from to build such a script on my own (note: I have very little programming knowledge so the easier the better)

TIA,
kristin

Comment: I think that would depend on what your site is.  I don't know how anyone can answer you without more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

[Search Mod](http://custom.simplemachines.org/mods/index.php?mod=1634)

Comment: I wasn't sure the OP was using SMF.

Comment: If OP isn't, then this question has very little chance of being answered due to its ambiguity.

Comment: Yes I am using SMF and while that mod is more focused on the forums themselves I believe I can extend it to search other parts of my site as well.